# Position and show the result of javascript code in html page

Tags: javascript, html

I want to display the result of my JavaScript code after taking the `input` from HTML form at 500px, 550px. But my code after displaying result once submit field goes away and only submit button stays. I can't fill the field again and re-submit it.

```js
function showcalculatedcost() {
  var x = document.getElementById("form1");
  var y = x.elements["name"].value;
  alert(y);
  document.getElementById("form1").innerHTML = 95 * y;
  document.getElementById("form1").setAttribute("style", "position: absolute; top: 500px; left: 500px");
}
```

```html
<form id="form1">
  Quantity:
  <input name="name" type="text" size="5">
</form>
<button onclick="showcalculatedcost()">Submit</button>
```

I want submit field to stay there. Thanks for helping.

Comment: There's a space in between onclick= "showcalculatedcost()" you need to remove it to make it work, like so: <button onclick="showcalculatedcost()">Submit</button>

Comment: why don't just apply css to the `form1` element so it displays at the desired position?

Comment: it's working for me...here's a fiddler to prove it (https://jsfiddle.net/k40x9v6r/) all I did was make the font bigger, just in case you have eye problems...

Comment: The content is displayed, you just have to scroll to get to it.

Comment: It works after the edits because the space that I was referring to is now gone :)

Comment: @DmitriyDemir it works even with the space...

Comment: Oh, never mind then...

Comment: I've edited the question. Please check it again.

Comment: @SamarYadav mate, the field goes away because you're clearing the whole form element...`document.getElementById("form1").innerHTML = 95 * y;` show the results somewhere else like a floating div or something

Comment: @Leo Can you help me out with floating div mate?

Comment: And who down vote the question and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> submit field goes away and only submit button stays

That's because the input is inside the form, and your JS replaces the inside of the form.

Put a div somewhere and replace the inside of that instead of altering the form.